# VBA macro to fill in cell based on 2 different fields that match to a list of values

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Button I want to assign a macro to that, when clicked, enters in the number 1 into a specific cell on another sheet within the same workbook. This macro needs to a) match the value in cell B8 to a range of values in another sheet column (G11:G110) and also b) match the value in cell C4 to a range of values in another sheet rows (L4:FR4).

So if the value in B8 = 01234 it will do a vlookup type function on G11:G110. Once it finds its match, it then looks at the value in C4 = "Application" and finds it match in L4:FR4. I should note that there are no duplicate values in any field and the values in L4:FR4 are static, whereas the values in cells G11:G110 change upon refresh.

I have tried Select Case, If...And...Then... and the only thing I got to work was simply saying 
If B8 = G11 Then blah blah L11
If B8 = G12 Then blah blah L12

```
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners1_Click()

Dim sourceSht As Worksheet: Set sourceSht = DataEntry
Dim destSht As Worksheet:   Set destSht = Labels
Dim Selection As Range:     Set Selection = DataEntry.Range("C5")' This is the # 1 I was talking about'
Dim Acct As Range:          Set Acct = DataEntry.Range("B8")
Dim SpecErr As Range:       Set SpecErr = DataEntry.Range("C4")

If (SpecErr.Value = Labels.Range("L4")) And (Acct.Value = Labels.Range("G11")) Then
    Selection.Copy Destination:=Labels.Range("L11")
End If
If (SpecErr.Value = Labels.Range("M4")) And (Acct.Value = Labels.Range("G11")) Then
    Selection.Copy Destination:=Labels.Range("M11")
End If
End Sub
```

I ran out of space in the code doing it like this, as I need to go from L4 to FR4, and then do this 100 times by adjusting G11 to G12 & L11 to L12 etc.

The sheet holding the main data and Button I called DataEntry, and the sheet that I need to lookup on and have the 1 entered on is called Labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need - you can just loop through all the columns (in your case, `12 to 175` represent L to FR), and then loop through rows `11 to 110`. Once you get a match, the destination cell is the corresponding column and row to `i` and `j`:

```
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners1_Click()

Dim sourceSht As Worksheet: Set sourceSht = DataEntry
Dim destSht As Worksheet:   Set destSht = Labels
Dim Selection As Range:     Set Selection = DataEntry.Range("C5") ' This is the # 1 I was talking about'
Dim Acct As Range:          Set Acct = DataEntry.Range("B8")
Dim SpecErr As Range:       Set SpecErr = DataEntry.Range("C4")

Dim i As Long, j As Long

For i = 12 To 175 'L to FR
    For j = 11 To 110
        If SpecErr.Value = Labels.Cells(4, i) And Acct.Value = Labels.Cells(j, 7) Then
            Selection.Copy Destination:=Labels.Cells(i, j)
        End If
     Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I had to modify the Selection.Copy line to end in (j, i), as the original was only copying to row 12. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does this have to be VBA? You could do this with a formula.  In sheet 'Labels' cell L11, use this formula and copy over and down:

```
=IF(AND(DataEntry!$B$8=$G11,DataEntry!$B$4=L$4),1,"")
```

If it must be VBA, then this can be done basically as a one-liner:

```
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners1_Click()

    On Error Resume Next    'Ignore errors if any fields are not filled out
    Sheets("Labels").Cells(Evaluate("MATCH(DataEntry!$B$8,Labels!$G:$G,0)"), Evaluate("MATCH(DataEntry!$B$4,Labels!$4:$4,0)")).Value = Sheets("DataEntry").Range("B5").Value
    On Error GoTo 0         'Clear "On Error Resume Next" condition

End Sub
```

Comment: The formula will not work, as I need the 1 to stay in each cell after I change B8. VBA didn't do the trick either. Thanks